# ASP MVC Assign Image from Model to View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an image in my model which I want to present in my view. I get data from a database and put that into my model, and I've already ensured that the image is actually in the model as well, so it should 'only' be a matter of presenting the image in the view.

This is what I've tried so far in my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li id="nav" class="@(item == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a id="id2"
                                                                      href="#tab-@item.Well" 
                                                                      data-toggle="tab""
                                                                      data-id="@item.Id"
                                                                      data-img="@item.Image">@item</a></li>
    }
</ul>

<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
    <h2 style="display: inline-block">ID: </h2>
    <h2 id="Header" style="display: inline-block"></h2>
    <br/>

    <h4 style="display: inline-block">Well#:</h4>
    <h4 id="Id" style="display: inline-block"></h4>

    <div id='chart_div'></div>
    <br/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>Picture here</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="image"> //This is where I want to put my image from the model
            <img src="" width="250"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the script I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("li a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var image = $(this).data("img");

    document.getElementById("Id").innerText = id;
    document.getElementById("image").value = Image;

});
</script>
```

I'm fairly confident that this method works, because I'm able to get the "Id" like this and put it into my view but I'm not quite sure how to do it with an image (bitmap) and this is not working. Any hint is appreciated!

This is the model:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6d71127-1f12-4555-879b-6a859947eafa.aspx

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer as it led to success ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer accepted by the OP from a comment comes from a suggestion to use the image data encoded as base64 string and inlined in the page body. This method works nowadays with most browsers.

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6d71127-1f12-4555-879b-6a859947eafa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name of an image instead of an object Image

```
public class Model
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
}
```

I suggest that your image is put in a Content/Image folder and image name is like "image.jpg", so you just have to do :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="image"> //This is where I want to put my image from the model
        <img src="@Html.Raw("Content/Image/"+item.Image)" width="250"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the img src instead of `document.getElementById("image").value = Image;